# How can I assign values to a mutated variable using outputs of if statements?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to assign a value of either "Apple," "Banana" or "other" if there is no missing value in that row of the data frame. There should only be one non-missing value per row.

```
A <- c(1,NA,3,NA,NA,6,NA)
B <- c(NA,2,NA,4,5,NA,NA)
C <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7)

fruit_df <- tibble(A,B,C)

fruit_counts <- fruit_df %>%
  mutate(
    vendor = if(is.na(A) == FALSE) { "Apple" }
              else if (is.na(B) == FALSE) { "Banana" }
              else { "other"}
  )
```

I'm getting a syntax error and not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the error message:

```
 Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `fruit_type`.
ℹ `fruit_type = if (...) NULL`.
ℹ the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Originally I just wanted to carry the column name (i.e., A, B, C) to denote where the values weren't missing. In other words, something like this:

```
  # A tibble: 7 x 4
      A     B     C fruit_type
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1    NA    NA A         
2    NA     2    NA B         
3     3    NA    NA A         
4    NA     4    NA B         
5    NA     5    NA B         
6     6    NA    NA A         
7    NA    NA     7 C
```

I wanted to be able to specify any number of columns by name and have a function search the rows and carry the column name into the new variable (fruit_type) where the value is not missing. I'm pretty sure I need apply functions for that. But honestly if it's too complex I'll type each out using if-else.

Comment: It seems you are asking for two separate things, (1) "trying to assign a value of either "Apple," "Banana" or "other" if there is no missing value in that row of the data frame" and (2) "I wanted to be able to specify any number of columns by name and have a function search the rows and carry the column name into the new variable (fruit_type) where the value is not missing". Which is it?

Answer (score 4):

Using `apply` in `base R`

```
fruit_df$fruit_type <- apply(fruit_df, 1, function(x) names(x)[!is.na(x)])
```

-output

```
fruit_df$fruit_type
[1] "A" "B" "A" "B" "B" "A" "C"
```

---

or with `max.col` in `base R`

```
names(fruit_df)[max.col(!is.na(fruit_df))]
```

---

or similar option in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
fruit_df %>% 
    rename_with(~ c("Apple", "Banana", "other")) %>% 
    transmute(fruit_type = names(.)[max.col(!is.na(.))]) %>% 
    bind_cols(fruit_df, .)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
      A     B     C fruit_type
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
1     1    NA    NA Apple     
2    NA     2    NA Banana    
3     3    NA    NA Apple     
4    NA     4    NA Banana    
5    NA     5    NA Banana    
6     6    NA    NA Apple     
7    NA    NA     7 other
```

Comment: Can you show this code in context? This solution as written is not executable.

Comment: @StephenPoole I showed 3 solutions and all of them works in my system

Comment: @StephenPoole not really sure what you are asking about context.  I used only your input dataset

Answer (score 4):

Let's take a look at your error message:

```r
 Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `fruit_type`.
ℹ `fruit_type = if (...) NULL`.
ℹ the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

First of all, it's actually a **warning**, so your code *did* do something but most likely not the thing you wanted it to. An **error** stops the function's execution.

In this case, your `if`-function looked like

```r
if(is.na(A) == FALSE) { "Apple" }
  else (...)
```

Unfortunately this `if`-function isn't vectorized. So:

```r
> is.na(A)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

is evaluated for every row of your data.frame and `if` takes only the first element of `is.na(A)`. Therefore the condition

```r
is.na(A) == FALSE
```

is equivalent to

```r
is.na(A)[1] == FALSE
```

which is `TRUE` (since `is.na(A)[1]` is `FALSE`). This causes your code to return `Apple` for each row of your data.frame. Assuming you don't want this behaviour, you should use the vectorized functions `ifelse` or `dplyr::if_else`.

As mentioned by @andrew_reece one alternative could be using `case_when`:

```r
library(dplyr)

fruit_df %>%
  mutate( 
    vendor = case_when(is.na(A) == FALSE ~ "Apple",
                       is.na(B) == FALSE ~ "Banana",
                       TRUE              ~  "other")
  )
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 4
      A     B     C vendor
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1    NA    NA Apple 
2    NA     2    NA Banana
3     3    NA    NA Apple 
4    NA     4    NA Banana
5    NA     5    NA Banana
6     6    NA    NA Apple 
7    NA    NA     7 other
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `if_else` or `case_when`:

```r
fruit_df %>%
  mutate(vendor = if_else(!is.na(A), "Apple", if_else(!is.na(B), "Banana", "other")))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
      A     B     C vendor
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1    NA    NA Apple 
2    NA     2    NA Banana
3     3    NA    NA Apple 
4    NA     4    NA Banana
5    NA     5    NA Banana
6     6    NA    NA Apple 
7    NA    NA     7 other
```

If you need `fruit_type` as well as `vendor` (your post isn't clear), you can use `rowwise()`:

```r
fruit_df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fruit_type = names(fruit_df)[!is.na(cur_data())],
         vendor = if_else(!is.na(A), "Apple", if_else(!is.na(B), "Banana", "other")))

# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Rowwise: 
      A     B     C fruit_type vendor
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <chr> 
1     1    NA    NA A          Apple 
2    NA     2    NA B          Banana
3     3    NA    NA A          Apple 
4    NA     4    NA B          Banana
5    NA     5    NA B          Banana
6     6    NA    NA A          Apple 
7    NA    NA     7 C          other
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another tidyverse solution: Ideas are mainly from akrun (row3 and row6).

```
library(tidyverse)
fruit_df %>% 
    rename_with(~ c("Apple", "Banana", "other")) %>% 
    mutate(across(1:3, ~case_when(!is.na(.) ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}'), .keep="unused") %>%
    unite(vendor, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
    bind_cols(fruit_df, .)
```

output:

```
  Apple Banana other vendor
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     1     NA    NA Apple 
2    NA      2    NA Banana
3     3     NA    NA Apple 
4    NA      4    NA Banana
5    NA      5    NA Banana
6     6     NA    NA Apple 
7    NA     NA     7 other
```